# Is that possible a telegram bot can remove messages from group

Tags: telegram-bot

i want create telegram bot .
It can join to the group and delete messages in group .
Is that possible a telegram bot can remove messages from group ? 
i search and some people say yes it possible , some people say no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now outdated, please see [Darkc0d3r's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45285278/5457433)

---

Using the Telegram Bot API? **No**, there is no such functionality as of now.

However you can if you are using the Telegram API, where you can use the [messages.deleteMessages](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.deleteMessages) method, which requires you to give it a list of message id's as a parameter.

Comment: Yes i use , but some friends tell me wrong news , thx for answer

Answer (score 7):

Check this link out, it seems the new bot API made it possible with some restrictions:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage
The following details are from telegram API page:

> - A message can only be deleted if it was sent less than 48 hours ago.
> - Bots can delete outgoing messages in groups and supergroups.
> - Bots granted can_post_messages permissions can delete outgoing messages in channels.
> - If the bot is an administrator of a group, it can delete any message there.
> - If the bot has can_delete_messages permission in a supergroup or a channel, it can delete any message there.

Returns True on success.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
bot.DeleteMessageAsync(chatId, messageId)
```

you should make it in a try catch in case the message doesn't exist anymore or you have a wrong messageId,

messageId is a property which you get in MessageEventArgs.Message,

Note: the chatId should be the Group/Channel chatId and not of the user who sent it, get that in Chat.Id property of MessageEventArgs.Message ...